# Mapeando a mesma classe de entidade para dois bancos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Boa Tarde terráqueos,

Sou iniciante em java e estou com a seguinte situação. Tenho dois bancos de dados, onde eu vou transferir os registro de um banco para o outro. Existe a possibilidade de fazer uma classe de Entidade ser mapeada pelos dois bancos?

Observações:

- A aplicação esta utilizando o EntityManagerFactory e da mesma eu
  instancio um EntityManger.

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla.
Bom, acho que a resposta para este problema está neste estudo: http://blog.caelum.com.br/acessando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-jpa-e-cdi/

Comment: Vlw @Marcos. Vou ler o artigo

Answer (score 2):

Tem sim. Em JPA você usa unidades de persistência, que representam bancos específicos. Se você quiser especificar mais de um banco é só declarar mais de uma unidade de persistência (PU) e criar os entity managers para cada uma delas. O arquivo persistence.xml que declara as PUs ficaria assim:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1">
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/banco1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />

<persistence-unit name="pu2">
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/banco2" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />
```

Aí para referenciar uma entidade que está no banco 1 você só precisa instanciar a pu1 na criação do entity manager:

```
EntityManager emPU1 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu1").createEntityManager();
```

Já para a entidade que está no banco 2 é só referenciar a pu2:

```
EntityManager emPU2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu2").createEntityManager();
```

Depois de consultar ambas as entidades, você pode fazer o seu DE-PARA e persistir como desejar o resultado final. Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Então, eu fiz dessa forma antes de posta a pergunta, porém, eu achei que estava fazendo da forma errado. Mas vi que estou no caminho certo...

Comment: É assim mesmo quando se usa JPA :)

Comment: Querendo aproveita o post para fazer uma pergunta básica para você, mas dfícil para mim rsrs. Então, você poderia me tirar uma dúvida em relação a como criar xml + beans no Spring  ?

Comment: Posso sim, faz a pergunta que eu respondo lá!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150518/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-o-arquivo-xml-do-spring