# Dúvidas sobre o arquivo XML do Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que utiliza JAVA SE + SPRING. Estou com algumas dúvidas em relação ao XML:

- Onde que eu crio o arquivo `xml` do `Spring` ?
- Qual o nome que eu dou para o `arquivo xml` ?
- O XML seria as configurações para a injeção de dependência do Spring
  ?

OBS: Estou em fase de aprendizagem. Desculpa-me se estou sendo ignorante.

Agradeço desde já pela atenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo as suas perguntas:

> Onde que eu crio o arquivo xml do Spring?

Se estiver usando um arquétipo maven, coloca ele na pasta resources do projeto (src/main/resources).

> Qual o nome que eu dou para o arquivo xml?

Pode ser qualquer um, mas costuma ser context.xml ou applicationContext.xml por se tratar de um arquivo que declara o que irá compor o contexto do Spring na aplicação.

> O XML seria as configurações para a injeção de dependência do Spring ?

A grosso modo sim. Mas tenha em mente que em versões mais novas do Spring é possível utilizar anotações e aí você não precisa mais declarar teus beans num arquivo xml, basta simplesmente anotá-los (@Component).

O Spring framework permite gerenciar melhor as dependências de uma aplicação utilizando o conceito de injeção de dependências. Gosto muito dos tutoriais do Mkyong e por isso vou te passar um link que é exatamente sobre Spring:

- Geral: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/
- Básico: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/

Atualmente os desenvolvedores tem utilizado mais o CDI com esse propósito, e é o que eu te recomendo fortemente a usar. Depois dá uma pesquisada a respeito, vai valer a pena.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) e fuja de XMLs desnecessários, realizando todas configurações por convenção e rastreamento do claspath da aplicação.